# Regex and returning two lists as a tuple

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have this function, that I would like to see if can be done more pythonic.
The function explains it self what it is trying to achieve.

My concern is that I'm using two regex expressions for `content` and `expected` that gives room for error creeping in, best would be if these two variables could use the same regex.

input example:

```
test_names = "tests[\"Status code: \" +responseCode.code] = responseCode.code === 200;\ntests[\"Schema validator GetChecksumReleaseEventForAll\"] = tv4.validate(data, schema);"

def custom_steps(self, test_names):
    """ Extracts unique tests from postman collection """
    content = re.findall(r'(?<=tests\[")(.*)(?::|"\])', test_names)
    expected = re.findall(r'(?<=\] = )(.*)(?::|;)', test_names)
    for i, er in enumerate(expected):
        if "===" in er:
            expected[i] = er[er.find('===')+4:]
        else:
            expected[i] = "true"

    return content, expected
```

Comment: Try `r'tests\["(.*?)(?::|"\]).*?=\s*(.*)[:;]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match both groups at the same time:

```
def custom_steps(self, test_names):
    regex = 'tests\["(.*)(?::|"\]).* = (.+)(?::|;)'
    for match in re.finditer(regex, test_names):
        content, expected = match.groups()
        if '===' in expected:
            expected = expected[expected.index('===') + 4:]
        else:
            expected = 'true'
        yield content, expected
```

This gives you a generator over pairs of `content`, `expected`:

```
for c, e in custom_steps(None, test_names):
    print c, e
```

Output:

```
Status code 200
Schema validator GetChecksumReleaseEventForAll true
```

Comment: great answer, nice to get the regex into one regex. Thanks man.